# Fast Fourier cosine transform for poisson equation with all zero Neumann boundary condition

Tags: c++, math, fft, differential-equations

I am trying to solve Poisson equation in rectangular domain by using Fast Fourier Cosine transform with FFTW3 library.

The boundary condition of four sides is zero Neumann boundary condition.

- The equation `d^u/dx^2+d^2u/dy^2=-f`
- with `f=cos(x)+cos(y)`, domain `[-pi pi,-pi pi]`
- exact solution is `u=f`.
- function `f` satisfy Neumann boundary condition.
- Drive the equation by using Fourier transform, we have:
- `U=F/(lamda(i)+lamda(j))`
- here `lamda(k)=2*(1-cos(i/(n0-1)))`
- and `U` is invert transformed to get small `u`.

However, i still get wrong result compared with exact solution.

Could you please help me? Thank you so much.

Here is my code

```cxx
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {

    int n0=64;
    int n1=64;

    int N=n0*n1;

    double pi = 3.14159265359;
    double L  = 2.*pi;
   double dx = L/(n0);

    double *in1=new double [N];
    double *in2=new double [N];
    double *out1=new double [N];
    double *out2=new double [N];
    double *X=new double [N];
    double *Y=new double [N];


    fftw_plan p, q;
    int i,j;
    p = fftw_plan_r2r_2d(n0,n1, in1, out1, FFTW_REDFT00, FFTW_REDFT00, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    q = fftw_plan_r2r_2d(n0,n1, in2, out2, FFTW_REDFT00, FFTW_REDFT00, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    for(i = 0;i <n0;i++){
        X[i] =-pi+i*dx ;
        for(j = 0;j<n1;j++){
            Y[j] = -pi+j*dx ;
            in1[i*n0 + j]= cos(X[i]) + cos(Y[j]) ; // row major ordering
        }
    }

    fftw_execute(p);

    double *lamda=new double [n0];

    for (i=0;i<n0;i++){
        lamda[i]=cos(pi*i/(n0-1));
    }

    for ( i= 0; i< n0; i++){   // f = g / ( lamda(ii)+lamda(jj) )  
        for( j = 0; j < n1; j++){

            double fact=0;
            in2[i*n0 + j]=0;

            fact=2*(2-lamda[i]-lamda[j]);

            if(fact!=0){
                in2[i*n0 + j] = out1[i*n0 + j]/fact;
            }else{
                in2[i*n0 + j] =0;
            }

        }
    }

    fftw_execute(q);

    double erl1 = 0.;
    for ( i = 0; i < n0; i++) {
        for( j = 0; j < n1; j++){

            cout<< i <<" "<< j<<" "<< cos(X[i])+cos(Y[j])<<" "<<  dx*dx*out2[i*n0+j]/(2.*(double)(n0-1))/(2.0*(double)(n1-1)) <<" "<< endl; 

        }
    }

    fftw_destroy_plan(p); fftw_destroy_plan(q); fftw_cleanup();
    delete [] in1;
    delete [] in2;
    delete [] out1;
    delete [] out2;
    delete [] X;
    delete [] Y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. write how do you try to solve this for those of us too lazy to analyze your code without background knowledge of what you are doing.  2. what do you mean by `Fast Fourier cosine transform` ??? DFCT is not DFFT. 3. what is your wanted solution output want set of points , function or what as output ? 4. which data is known and which not ?